# chmod 755 hello.cgi

Tags: cgi

I use ssh. I created a cgi-bin directory and deploy a simple progeam called `hello.cgi`

Then I gave a permission:

```
> chmod 755 hello.cgi
```

When I try to enter my website I get the following message:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: -1 For a bad title, and bad grammar (regarding "*i use ssh . i created a cgi-bin directory [...]*").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message normally happens when the server encounters an error when running your cgi script. For the best clues on what that error is, as suggested by the error given by apache (your webserver) check the error log (which can vary from installation to installation, but is often found in places like /var/log/apache2/error_log or /usr/local/apache2/logs/error_log)

Comment: No problem, if this was the answer that correct could you mark it as so? (There are too many brainiacs on this site and getting a decent score is hard work ;)

Comment: Aha, glad you sorted it out (hopefuly the output from the apache log file was some help, I imagine some 'permission denied' error :)

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether your cgi-bin directory really granted with CGI rights.
- Ensure your script can be executed by the user which runs the web server. It didn't run using your login.

Write a hello world first!

Comment: how do i check if  cgi-bin directory granted with CGI rights?